# Editing featureclass in Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY

Tags: editing, feature-class, oracle-dbms, sdo-geometry

I'm building an empty featureclass in Oracle and want to enable editing in arcmap/py with having the featureclass user SDO_GEOMETRY for the shape column. However, I'm running into difficulties on how the information is being stored. I'm receiving this error when trying to edit a few vertices and save.
[image]

The idea here is that Oracle could populate this table's SDO_GEOMETRY column from other sources/tables/applications and then this table could be viewed in ArcMap and also edited if needed.

The featureclass is Registered as Versioned.

Comment: It's very nearly *worst* practice to create data tables owned by the SDE login (best practice is to create one or more "owner" logins to manage table definition, then one or more logins for table access, one or more roles to manage access rights). It is exceedingly difficult to edit versioned geometry via SQL. It is easy to edit geometry from SQL when not versioned. Are you sure you need this table versioned?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the error message as text, and to specify the exact editing changes you attempted (since this error generally doesn't have anything to do with geometry)